# Can this be simplified

Tags: python

I have written this program, but I am not sure whether it can be simplified. Thanks,

Code:

```
ISBN=input('Please enter the 10 digit number: ')

while len(ISBN)!= 10:
    print('Please make sure you have entered a number which is exactly 10 characters long.')
    ISBN=int(input('Please can you enter the 10 digit number: '))
    continue
else:
    Digit1=int(ISBN[0])*11
    Digit2=int(ISBN[1])*10
    Digit3=int(ISBN[2])*9
    Digit4=int(ISBN[3])*8
    Digit5=int(ISBN[4])*7
    Digit6=int(ISBN[5])*6
    Digit7=int(ISBN[6])*5
    Digit8=int(ISBN[7])*4
    Digit9=int(ISBN[8])*3
    Digit10=int(ISBN[9])*2
    Sum=(Digit1+Digit2+Digit3+Digit4+Digit5+Digit6+Digit7+Digit8+Digit9+Digit10)
    Mod=Sum%11
    Digit11=11-Mod
    if Digit11==10:
       Digit11='X'
    ISBNNumber=str(ISBN)+str(Digit11)
    print("Your final answer nuber is " + ISBNNumber)
```

Comment: What're you trynig to do? You're asking the user to input a 10-digit ISBN, and then after some calculation, you're appending either 'X' or 10 to the 10-digit ISBN. Did I understand correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure if your algo is correct (and not sure about the language you're using), but the sum calculation can certainly be simplified with a for loop

```
sum = 0

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    sum += (ISBN[i] * (11 - i))
 }
```

Comment: I am using python if that helps you.

Comment: @Phil and I'm sure it would be fine to learn how to iterate an array in python...